# iphone - access uitableviewcontroller from uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a structure like this....

```
UITableViewController -> UITableViewCell -> UIView
```

I need the `UIView` to access a HashTable (`NSMutableDictionary`) in the `UITableViewController`

Is there a way to access the ViewController simply from the ViewCell (using [ViewCell superview] obviously won't work) ....Do I need to go down through the AppDelegate using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually maintain a weak reference from my UIView to my UIViewController if I need one, usually by creating a method something like this:

```
-(MyView*)initWithController:(CardCreatorViewController*) aController andFrame:(CGRect)aFrame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:aFrame]) 
    {
       controller = aController;
       // more initialisation here
    }

    return self;
}
```

You could also use a delegate pattern if you want a more decoupled solution. I tend to think this is overkill for a view and its controller, but I would use it with a system of controllers and subcontrollers.

Answer (score 27):

This should do the trick:

```
UITableView *tv = (UITableView *) self.superview.superview;
UITableViewController *vc = (UITableViewController *) tv.dataSource;
```

Comment: I'm using iOS 5.0 and this is not working in my current project, self.superview.superview is a UIView and not a UITableView ("[UIView dataSource]: unrecognized selector").

Comment: @Max nothing in the documentation guarantees that table view cells will be two subviews down from table views so this answer relies on undocumented behaviour. It's not surprising that it's broken.

Comment: You should use this: UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.superview;

Comment: I'll have to agree with @Tommy here, this is not a good way of doing it. Me 6 years ago didn't know what he was talking about.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a category for this:

```
@implementation UITableViewCell (FindTableViewController)

- (id<UITableViewDataSource>)tableViewController
{
    UIView *view = self;
    while (!(view == nil || [view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])) {
        view = view.superview;
    }

    return ((UITableView *)view).dataSource;
}

@end
```

Then you can simply access `self.tableViewController` from the cell itself (assuming you have included this category). You may need to cast it to your table view controller's class tho.

Answer (score 4):

Since the UITableViewCell is somewhere in the view hierarchy, you can access your root view by retrieving view.superview until you get it.  If you don't want to add any properties to your view, you can access its controller through the view's `nextResponder` property.  You would have to cast it to whatever class you need, of course, and it may not be the cleanest use of the property.  It's a quick-n-dirty hack to get to it.

If you're looking for something you can show your children though, I'd aim for going through your app delegate, or if your view controller happens to be a singleton, just implement the singleton design pattern and access it through that.

Answer (score 4):

Some modification from Kare Morstol answer :

The hierarchy of tableviewcell is in iOS 5.0(my test version)

```
cell.superview = tableview  
cell.superview.superview = UIViewControllerWrapperView
```

So, use cell.superview to get tableview. And the tableview and tableviewController has a relation of delegate, dataSource in default.
You can get tableviewController reference by `tableview.delegate` or `tableview.dataSource`.

```
UITableView *tableView = cell.superview;  
UITableViewController *tableViewController = tableView.delegate; // or tableView.dataSource`
```