# how to load a popup from an uibutton in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app i've got a view controller with a table view.

Inside of one `UITableviewCell` there's an uibutton which, on click, should show a popup view.

Inside my project i've already imported `KGModal` framework for popups with works properly in other view controllers , but if i try to show popup view here, it seems that it tries to show the view inside the cell, with bad results.

Does anyone know how can i solve it?

I think that the problem is that i should "traverse" the hierarchy and go to tableview's superviewcontroller and then show it, but i don't know how to do it and i don't know if it's the right solution for the problem.

If you need it i can post without any problem.

I can say that the code which "should" show the popup view is :

```
[[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:_vistapopup andAnimated:YES];
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post your error?.

Comment: i don't have any error, i can post 2 screenshot in which i show what it should do and what it does instead!

Comment: Do you have a separate view-controller for your tableViewCell? Do you perform this piece *[[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:_vistapopup andAnimated:YES];* of code in tableViewCell's controller? If no, then does your tableViewController derive from UITableView or UIView?  I've never heard of KGModal, but these questions should help to find the solution in the end

Comment: well, i've created a custom uitableviewcell, with an indipendent XIB and everything works properly. Inside of it i've added an UIButton in Interface Builder, so i have to do this piece of code inside of UITableviewCell's controller. I think that if i access to the botton in his subclass (so in the cell's superviewcontroller) it works, but i don't know how to access to the uibutton in the superviewcontroller.. i hope to be understandable..

Comment: Whats is _vistapopup ?

Comment: _vistapopup is the view which should show in popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem, because you must place the popup creation code in some method of TableViewController, not of CellViewController. In you button's 'touchUpInside' callback you want to invoke that TableViewController's method. And the question is actually:  "**How to reach a TableViewController object from its TableCellViewController child?**" Looking at your comments I suppose we're agreed with that.

Try to take a look at [**this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828777/iphone-access-uitableviewcontroller-from-uitableviewcell).

I personally like most the Ed Marty's answer: either a reaching your TableViewController object from the very appDelegate, or a singleton solution. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, you perfectly understood my problem! now i'm taking a look at the topic and i'll let you know if it solves my problem :)

Comment: I've not found any solution yet.. is there a way in which you can show me how to do it? I'm really sorry about my question, but i find a little difficult to understand how to solve my problem.. :(

Comment: Well, first try to use the most straightforward attempt:  in your TableCellViewController button callback try to do this  *UITableView *tableView = self.superview; YourTableViewController *tableController = (YourTableViewController\*)tableView.dataSource; [tableController yourTableFancyMethod];*  And if the compiler says you 'unrecognized selector' on dataSource, then later I'll edit my answer to contain more details

Comment: Glad it helped :-), but note that you shouldn't rely on this too much, just maybe for some test project. If you're planning to deploy your project in production, you should consider more robust solutions (like singleton or reaching of your table object through appDelegate tree).

Comment: it's only a popup view which shows threes buttons which send a callback, it's not a massive request..overall i need it only in one `UIButton`, so it a perfect solution for now..in the future i'll consider the singleton for a better performance ;) thank you :)